# use jquery to enable textbox on button click

Tags: jquery

How do I enable a textbox on a link button click, I'm disabling the textbox in the html

Here is the jquery code I'm trying to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lEdit').click(function () {
            $('#CorporationName').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lEdit" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" >Edit</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Label ID="lblCorporationName" runat="server" Text="Corporation Name" Width="130px"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="CorporationName" runat="server" Width="250px" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're doing it right. If that isn't working, try:

```
$('#CorporationName').prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

While setting a property to false or even null might work, you might want to try [jQuery's `removeProp()` function](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/). It's designed to do just that.

> Description: Remove a property for the set of matched elements.

```
$('#CorporationName').removeProp('disabled');
```

---

Be aware, once you remove the property in this way, you won't be able to disable the textbox again.

Comment: Actually, it is recommended that you don't use it for that purpose. From [.removeProp()](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/): _Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead._